# error message : from selenium import webdriver "I install selenium in my pc windows 10 and I use Spyder to run python code"

Tags: python, selenium, spyder

I installed selenium in my pc windows 10 then I tried to run selenium in `Spyder` from anaconda. But the error message is shown

```
from selenium import webdriver Import error:cannot import 'webdriver'
```

Code:

```
from selenium import webddriver
driver=webddriver.Ie("C:\\users......")
```

what is the problem? have I import selenium to spyder and how? or have I but the selenium in which path?

Comment: Is this file you're trying to run called `selenium.py`? or do you have a file called `selenium.py` in your working directory?

Comment: How did you install Spyder, and how did you install selenium? I assume we're talking about the [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/) web browser automation framework.

Comment: selenium is a library by python. and Spyder in with in anaconda

Comment: when I trying import selenium. "import selenium" the error message shown: "reloaded model:selenium"